# Random number generator rarely includes upper and lower bounds

Tags: javascript

I have some letters in an array, only 8 of them, starting at A and ending at H. Using a typical random number generator, I have found that A and H are very rarely generated. How can I make this more inclusive for these two bounds?

```js
var allowedLetters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];
var i = Math.round(Math.random() * (allowedLetters.length - 1));
var letter = allowedLetters[i];
    
console.log(letter)
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that this code will ever generate J...

Comment: `return Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedLetters.length)`  IOW: not `Math.round()` and `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var i = Math.round(Math.random() * (allowedLetters.length - 1));
```

Cause the first and the last element got a range of `0.5`, all the others got `1`. Might do this instead:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedLetters.length);
```

Were all elements get the same distribution.

Answer (score 1):

`round` is is wrong, because only half of the slot of the random values goes to the lower index and half of the slot goes to the upper index.

```js
var values = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
    index,
    count = {},
    i = 1e6;

while (i--) {
    index = Math.round(Math.random() * (values.length - 1));
    count[values[index]] = (count[values[index]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(count);
```

You could use `Math.floor` with the full length of the array as factor.

```js
var values = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
    index,
    count = {},
    i = 1e6;

while (i--) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
    count[values[index]] = (count[values[index]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allowedLetters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];
var calledTimes = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var i = 0;

while (i++ < 100000) calledTimes[Math.round(Math.random() * (allowedLetters.length - 1))]++;

console.log(calledTimes);
```

This happens because of `Math.round` specifics. Use `Math.floor` instead:

```js
var allowedLetters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];
var calledTimes = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var i = 0;

while (i++ < 100000) calledTimes[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedLetters.length)]++;

console.log(calledTimes);
```